# How to use Single observable operator with Location object

Tags: android, observable, reactive-programming

In the below code I am trying to use Single observale with object of type Locations. I want to broadcast lat,long,alt and acc. all of them is of type double unlike the last one is of type float.

```
         Single.just(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 
  location.getAltitude(), location.getAccuracy());
```

how can the above code be amended to accommodate all the different types of double and float.

**code**

```
        Single.just( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 
 location.getAltitude(), location.getAccuracy());
```

Comment: `Single` has only one value. Do you actually want to have a stream of values? Otherwise you could do `Single.just(location)` as well.

Comment: WHy wouldn't you just broadcase a single object (the Location object, or a POJO created out of it if you have reasons not to want to keep a reference to it directly) rather than send the values separately?

Comment: @GabeSechan because if i am gonna broadcast a single objetc i have to implement serializable to add it to the extra of the intent

Comment: Observable don't need to be serializable. But even if they did, create a pojo with those 4 fields and send that instead. Then make that pojo serializable (which is as simple as adding an annotation)

Comment: @GabeSechan isnt there any any way to add casting to all entries in the single obsevale..for example to use generics

Comment: First off, this won't work anyway- singles have a single value not 4. Although a pojo would work. Second, no. You'd have to make then take a common base class and cast, like number or object. Third, a pojo of the right way, will make your code easier to read, provide lower coupling, and takes 12 lines max